# C Buscar y escribir en un archivo txt

Tags: c

Necesito ayuda: / este programa se supone que busca un texto en un archivo txt, si este texto está allí, entonces genera otro texto y si ese no está lo escribe. 
por ejemplo:

Genero aleatoreamente INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (2,4); Y miro en el txt si se encuentra este texto, si no está entonces lo escribo en el txt.

luego genera INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (5,7); Lo busco en el txt, si no está, lo escribo en el txt

después genera INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (2,4); Lo busco en el txt, como está en el, entonces no lo escribo y genero otro de nuevo. y así

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //strlen
#include <stdio.h>
int NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
#define fila 100 

int main()
{
    char aux[200];
    char aux2[200];
    int contador=0;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("prueba.txt","a+"); 
    if(f==NULL)
    {
        printf("no se ha podido abrir el archivo");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i,num_prof,num_alum=1;

    num_prof = NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
    fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof); //escribo en el fichero f
    num_alum++;

    for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
    {
        num_prof = NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
        sprintf(aux,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof); //almaceno el valor en aux

        while(!feof(f))
        {
            fgets(aux2,200,f); //I read from the file f and I keep each line in aux2

            if(strcmp(aux,aux2) == 0 ) //If a1 and a2 are equal then it is repeated.
            {
                contador=1;
            }
            memset(aux2, '\0',200);  //Vacio el array aux2
        }
        memset(aux, '\0',200);
        if(contador==0)
        {
            fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof);
        }

        num_alum++;
    }
    fclose(f);
}
//Random Number
int NUMEROS_AL_PROFE()
{
    int num;
    num = rand() % 17 + 1; //Numeros aleatorios entre 1 y 17
    num = num + 1; 
    return num;
}
```

El programa compila y al ejecutar se queda pegado y en el txt no escribe nada a simple vista, pero se llena ya que puede pesar hasta 1 gb, no tengo idea lo que está escribiendo :l

Comment: a simple vista no parece haber nada raro.. probaste escribir menos filas a ver si termina??

Comment: probé con pocos pero tampoco funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás abriendo el fichero en modo edición avanzada...

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("prueba.txt","a+");
```

Después empiezas a escribir en el fichero:

```
num_prof = NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof); //escribo en el fichero f
```

Y de repente te da por buscar en el fichero:

```
while(!feof(f))
```

¿Qué esperas encontrar ahí? Estás escribiendo en el fichero luego el puntero va a estar al final del fichero... eso si no acabas teniendo problemas con la caché del stream...

Lo que tienes que hacer es posicionarte al principio del fichero antes de cada búsqueda...y por supuesto garantizar que te posicionas al final del fichero antes de cada escritura. Aunque pueda parecer trivial hacer esto hay que tener en cuenta ciertas [consideraciones](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek):

> **Notes**
>
> After seeking to a non-end position in a wide stream, the next call to any output function may render the remainder of the file undefined, e.g. by outputting a multibyte sequence of a different length.
>
> For text streams, the only valid values of offset are ​0​ (applicable to any origin) and a value returned by an earlier call to ftell (only applicable to SEEK_SET).
>
> POSIX allows seeking beyond the existing end of file. If an output is performed after this seek, any read from the gap will return zero bytes. Where supported by the filesystem, this creates a sparse file.
>
> POSIX also requires that fseek first performs fflush if there are any unwritten data (but whether the shift state is restored is implementation-defined).

Resumiendo:

- Al trabajar con ficheros *no ASCII* escribir en posiciones aleatorias del fichero puede resultar en comportamientos no definidos. Es decir, puedes acabar fastidiando la codificación del fichero).
- Al trabajar en modo texto el único offset válido es 0. La única excepción son los valores devueltos por `ftell` (y en este caso debes usar `SEEK_SET`)
- **OJO a este**: POSIX admite la búsqueda de elementos más allá del final fichero. Eso sí, si se te ocurre escribir pasado dicho límite las búsquedas en las regiones intermedias no obtendrán resultado.
- `fseek` requiere que vacies el buffer del fichero. (Este punto puede ser importante para explicar tu problema.)

Así pues tu algoritmo quizás debiera quedar más o menos así:

```
FILE *f;
f = fopen("prueba.txt","a+"); 
if(f==NULL)
{
    printf("no se ha podido abrir el archivo");
    exit(1);
}

int i,num_prof,num_alum=1;

num_prof = NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof); //escribo en el fichero f
num_alum++;

for(i=0;i<fila;i++)
{
    num_prof = NUMEROS_AL_PROFE();
    sprintf(aux,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof); //almaceno el valor en aux

    fflush(f);
    int pos = ftell(f);
    fseek(f,0,SEEK_SET);
    while(!feof(f))
    {
        fgets(aux2,200,f); //I read from the file f and I keep each line in aux2

        if(strcmp(aux,aux2) == 0 ) //If a1 and a2 are equal then it is repeated.
        {
            contador=1;
            break; // No hace falta seguir buscando, cierto?
        }
        // memset(aux2, '\0',200); --> no es necesario
    }
    // memset(aux, '\0',200); --> no es necesario

    fseek(f,pos,SEEK_SET);
    if(contador==0)
    {
        fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof);
    }
```

---

**2ª revisión**

se me pasó un pequeño detalle: la variable `contador` no se resetea **nunca**. En consecuencia, en cuanto el algoritmo encuentre la primera línea duplicada dejará de añadir nuevas líneas. Deberías reiniciar el valor en cada iteración (una posibilidad):

Otro detalle raro que le veo al programa es que **siempre** va a insertar una línea por ejecución, la primera línea se inserta siempre sin importar si ya existe.

Y, para finalizar, esto:

```
if(contador==0)
{
    fprintf(f,"INSERT INTO ALUM_PROF VALUES (%d,%d);\n",num_alum,num_prof);
}
```

Puede ser sustituído por esto:

```
if(contador==0)
{
    fprintf(f,"%s",aux);
}
```

Creo que no merece explicación, si la cadena a almacenar en el fichero ya está generada y almacenada en `aux` no veo necesidad de volver a generarla.

A mí el programa me funciona correctamente. Si sigue sin funcionarte, o estás copiando algo mal o las librerías que usas son defectuosas.

Comment: amigo, gracias por responder, lamentablemente no funciona el codigo, no se cuál es el problema... compila  y ejecuta pero se queda procesando algo... y en el txt imprime solo 2 elementos
respecto a la pregunta que me hiciste 

**"....Y de repente te da por buscar en el fichero:
while(!feof(f))
¿Qué esperas encontrar ahí?"** lo que espero encontrar es que no haya ningún elemento igual antes de ingresarlo para que no haya texto repetido, así como explique en el ejemplo :)

Comment: El codigo que me adjunto eferion tampoco funciona :l no entiendo los motivos...
ni siquiera sé cual es el error ya que el programa compila bien :S

Comment: @EmiliOrtega he actualizado la respuesta. Espero que te sirva

Comment: ya descubrí el problema, aunque no es un problema , es solo un error de logica, se suponia que si definí fila en el for para 10 elementos, yo quería que se imprimieran 10 elementos No repetidos en el txt, pero lo que está haciendo es imprimir solo los que no se repiten y iterando solo 10, por eso imprime 4 en el txt por ejemplo, ya que hubieron 6 elementos repetidos XD

Comment: @EmiliOrtega por eso es muy importante elaborar las preguntas de forma concisa... si tu hubieses dicho que quieres eso alguien se habría dado cuenta de ese error... aun así eso no tiene nada que ver con el hecho de que te generase ficheros de 1GB. En cualquier caso si esta pregunta solucionó el problema que figura en la pregunta te agradecería que la marcases como solución. Así ayudarás a futuros visitantes

Comment: exacto, de todos modos te agradezco la ayuda pero insisto que algo malo tiene tu codigo tambien amigo, no hace lo que deberia porque le puse un contador dentro de esta sentencia** if(strcmp(aux,aux2) == 0 )
        {
            cont = cont+1;
            contador=1;
            break; // No hace falta seguir buscando, cierto?
        }**
y cuando imprimo el valor final de ese contador, es 2 por ejemplo el resultado y si reviso el txt hay solo 4 elementos insertados, siendo que fila tiene un valor de 20 por ejemplo , me entiendes?

Comment: @EmiliOrtega creo que no te he entendido. La primera versión de la respuesta trata de evitar que se generen, como decías, ficheros de 1Gb... la modificación vino motivada porque te quejabas de que seguía sin funcionar (mi cometido no es dejar tu código niquelado sino resolverte dudas). No entiendo tus quejas. Por otro lado si te digo que marques la respuesta como solución no es por conseguir reputación sino para que la gente que venga sepa que la respuesta soluciona lo planteado en la pregunta... que es precisamente que tu código generaba ficheros enormes sin datos aparentes

Comment: No me quejo, de hecho te agradecí tu respuesta, pero simplemente te comento que tu funciona del todo :s eso es todo y no la he marcado como resuelta por el hecho de que quizás alguien pueda plantear otra solución mas factible que solucione el problema de generar archivos de 1 GB y que a la vez quede funcionando al igual que el tuyo pero al 100%

Comment: ya lo solucioné :D ahora esta funcionando, te daré el punto! solo te queria hacer una pregunta, porque los memset(aux2, '\0',200); y memset(aux, '\0',200); no son necesarios ? si yo estoy escribiendo en esos arreglos por ejemplo se escribe "prueba" y si no utilizo el memset y posteriormente vuelva a escribir en arreglo la palabra "casa" entonces en ela rreglo quedaria escrito "casaeb" y ese **eb** es de la palabra anterior :O
y la otra duda es , para que es el flush(f) ?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64843/discussion-between-eferion-and-emiliortega).